# How do I use align_image_stack to create the bullet-time effect?

Tags: auto-alignment

I'm trying to do a bullet time effect with nine cameras (for a first test). Obviously, the cameras are not aligned, even with a minimal gap, and the final effect is not smooth.

I've found that the line command, [align_image_stack](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-align_image_stack/) (on Linux) can align two photos but I don't know if it is a good way or not to do this. I've tried to launch with the 9 photos and the command is still running after 30 minutes (my computer has an i7 processor, and 32GB RAM. :D).

So I've tried by pair but I don't know how to optimize the set up (the render is not great).

If you can help me ... I post my photos:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I think you may be drastically underestimating the amount of work and calibration of camera positioning, and specialized software required to do a bullet-time video. For example, see [this xangle camera server video on how they do it](https://xanglecs.com/blog/getting-started-with-bullet-time-new-basic-tutorial).

Answer (score 3):

Your images have different points of view which I believe is beyond align_image_stack (AIS) capability. 
AIS is meant for aligning images slightly off from each other that are taken from the same view point. This is to facilitate stacking images for HDR, focus stacking, and noise reduction stacking. AIS will also attempt to compensate for slight magnification changes which is an issue when focus stacking.